# IE 10 Does Not Render Updated Flash SWF's

Tags: flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer, browser-cache, internet-explorer-10

I am using the following code to display flash content on webpage -

```
<embed src="test_flash_file.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
    width="100%" height="100%" name="fclient" align="middle"
    play="true"
    loop="false"
    quality="high"
    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
</embed>
```

This works fine with no issues in all browsers. However, when I make any modification in **test_flash_file.swf** and update this file in the directory, IE 10 would still render the earlier flash file and not the updated one. This doesn't happen in other browsers or lower versions of IE (7, 8).

Looks like IE 10 reads from cache. is there any way to stop IE 10 from doing so ?

*(Note: I am using Adobe Flex Builder to export release build)*

Comment: Empty cache and refresh ? Disable cache ? Add a dynamically generated parameter to your flash source... what did you try ?

Comment: All browsers will cache files and I have problems like that for all clients across many different browsers.  For development, you can turn off the cache; but it won't be practical to do so for your users.  For enterprise applications, it is generally considered 'okay' to instruct users to clear the cache when a new build is released into production.  Often a "control-shift-reload" will do it.  If you are targetting a less controlled environment; then @Bartdude has the right idea. The dynamically generated parameter will make the SWF seem like a new, uncached file to the browser.

Comment: You can also rename the SWF everytime you push a build into production.

Comment: @Reboog711 Right. Thats my problem. I cant tell users to clear/disable cache and also renaming SWF everytime seems too toilsome. I am considering using a random number as a parameter. Can you tell me how can I make use if it ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the browsers from caching, and if you can use PHP in your webpage, you can include it like this:

```
<embed src="test_flash_file.swf?version=<?php echo filemtime('test_flash_file.swf'); ?>"
    quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
    width="100%" height="100%" name="fclient" align="middle"
    play="true"
    loop="false"
    quality="high"
    allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
</embed>
```

This way whenever the swf is updated, its file time is changed and so the browser is forced to download it again.
Credit goes to [Dave Keen](http://www.actionscriptdeveloper.co.uk/how-to-stop-swfs-caching-in-the-browser-once-and-for-all/).